# Is destructuring this possible?

Tags: javascript, destructuring

I am new to destructuring and need help finding the best solution. I have a pretty complicated object coming back as a response and would like to clean it up. Without doing anything, it looks like this:

```
const homeTeam = {

totalPlaysFor: res.data.stats.home.teamStats[0].miscellaneous.offensePlays,

totalPlaysAgainst: res.data.stats.away.teamStats[0].miscellaneous.offensePlays

}
```

I know I can do something like:

```
const { offensePlays } = res.data.stats.home.teamStats[0].miscellaneous;
```

but that only solves my problem for one of them and would leave the other still long and tough to read.

Comment: No, don't use destructuring here. If you find yourself duplicating code, use helper functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can destructure the `stats` property in advance, then make a helper function that takes the `.home` or `.away` object and navigates to the nested `.offensePlays`:

```
const { stats } = res.data;
const getOffPlays = obj => obj.teamStats[0].miscellaneous.offensePlays;
const homeTeam = {
  totalPlaysFor: getOffPlays(stats.home),
  totalPlaysAgainst: getOffPlays(stats.away)
};
```

Without having a standalone helper function, you could also create the object by `.map`ping an array of properties (eg `[['totalPlaysFor', 'home'], ['totalPlaysAgainst', 'away']]`) and pass it to `Object.fromEntries`, but that would be significantly less readable IMO.

Comment: Just implemented this for the all of my properties that fall under this situation and it seems to be working as intended. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

While you can destructure this directly, via something like

```js
const {
  data: {
    stats: {
      home: {
        teamStats: [{
          miscellaneous: {
            offensePlays: totalPlaysFor
          }
        }]
      },
      away: {
        teamStats: [{
          miscellaneous: {
            offensePlays: totalPlaysAgainst
          }
        }]
      }
    }
  }
} = res

const homeTeam = {totalPlaysFor, totalPlaysAgainst}
```

that feels pretty ugly.

Regardless whether you think your code is ugly, I can see a much more important problem with it: it doesn't work when any of those properties doesn't exist. To solve that, you might want a feature not yet ubiquitous in the language, one of [Optional Chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) that would avoid throwing errors for a nested path such as `'data?.stats?.home?.teamStats?.0?.miscellaneous?.offensePlays'`, simply returning `undefined` if one of the nodes mentioned does not exist.

An equivalent feature is available as a function in many libraries.  [Underscore](https://underscorejs.org/)'s [`property`](https://underscorejs.org/#property), [lodash](https://lodash.com/)'s [`property`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#property), and [Ramda](https://ramdajs.com/)'s [`path`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#path) offer slightly different versions of this.  (Disclaimer: I'm a Ramda author.)  However it's easy enough to write our own:

```js
const getPath = (pathStr) => (obj) =>
  pathStr .split ('.')
    .reduce ((o, p) => (o || {}) [p], obj)

const res = {data: {stats: {home: {teamStats: [{miscellaneous: {offensePlays: "foo"}}]}, away: {teamStats: [{miscellaneous: {offensePlays: "bar"}}]}}}}

const homeTeam = {
  totalPlaysFor: getPath ('data.stats.home.teamStats.0.miscellaneous.offensePlays') (res),
  totalPlaysAgainst: getPath ('data.stats.away.teamStats.0.miscellaneous.offensePlays') (res)
}

console .log (homeTeam)
```

Note that the array is not delineated in this simple version as `[0]` but just as `.0`.  Obviously we could make this more sophisticated if necessary.

Comment: I don't see any advantage of `getPath` here. The code is just as repetitive as, and even a bit longer than, the original code. Also what does this question have to do with optional chaining?

Comment: @Bergi: Perhaps the OP wasn't worried about the concerns optional chaining solves; I certainly think about it when I see such a deeply nested path. `getPath` solves a similar problem.  It allows for a null-safe traversal of a path.  I did not try to solve the redundancy problem; I simply demonstrated how one could in fact use destructuring for this.  I then added how I would solve it, as I don't like to leave in an answer only code I dislike.  While we could write some function so that this becomes `homeTeam = {foo('home', foo('away')}`, that function would still need to handle this concern.

Comment: Ah, now I understand the angle of your answer better. Instead of writing "*If you don't like the code you've presented, one possible reason is that you want a feature not yet ubiquitous in the language*", it should read something like "*Regardless whether you think your code is ugly, I can see a much more important problem with it: it doesn't work when any of those properties doesn't exist. To solve that, …*"

Answer (score -1):

You can destructure as much as you want!

```js
const homeTeam = {
  totalPlaysFor: res.data.stats.home.teamStats[0].miscellaneous.offensePlays,
  totalPlaysAgainst: res.data.stats.away.teamStats[0].miscellaneous.offensePlays
}
```

You can even use a combination of array destructuring / object destructuring here:

```js
const [ home ] = res.data.stats.home.teamStats
const [ away ] = res.data.stats.away.teamStats

const { offensePlays: totalPlaysFor } = home.miscellaneous
const { offensePlays: totalPlaysAgainst } = away.miscellaneous

const hometeam = { totalPlaysFor, totalPlaysAgainst }
```

Or, if you want a more reusable solution, you can use parameter destructuring:

```js
const getTeam = (
  { miscellaneous: { offensePlays: totalPlaysFor } },
  { miscellaneous: { offensePlays: totalPlaysAgainst } }
) => ({
  totalPlaysFor,
  totalPlaysAgainst
})
```

Then you can use it like:

```js
const [ home ] = res.data.stats.home.teamStats
const [ away ] = res.data.stats.away.teamStats
const homeTeam = getTeam(home, away)
```